# I am making a memory game. How do I randomize the images in my gridview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, random, gridview

I am trying to randomize the images shown in my 4x4 grid for a memory card game. But I do not know how. Could someone help me.

I am very lost, the game itself works but does not randomise the images like i want it to. I have tried various methods but my knowledge of java is not deep enough. This is for  a small project and we have yet to be taught randomising and

### My game activity

```
public class Game extends AppCompatActivity { 
//Variables 
ImageView curView = null; 
private int countPair = 0; 
//Score 
private TextView scoreLabel; 
private int score = 0; 
//Tries 
private int tries = 0; 
private TextView tryLabel; 
//Attempts 
private int attempt = 10; 
private TextView attemptlabel; 
//FinalScore 
private TextView finalscore;

//The cards images initialised
final int[] drawable = new int[] {
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.two,
        R.drawable.three,
        R.drawable.four,
        R.drawable.five,
        R.drawable.six,
        R.drawable.seven,
        R.drawable.eight,
        R.drawable.nine,
        R.drawable.ten,
        R.drawable.eleven,
        R.drawable.jack,
        R.drawable.king,
        R.drawable.trump};
//Position of the cards / variables
int[] pos = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int currentPos = -1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    //Hides action bar
    getSupportActionBar().hide();


    //Changes score text
    scoreLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreText);
    scoreLabel.setText("Score : 0");

    //Changes try text
    tryLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tries);
    tryLabel.setText("Tries : 0");

    //Changes attempt text
    attemptlabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.attemptext);
    attemptlabel.setText("Attempts left : 10");

    //Change text for final score
    finalscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);

    //Initialises as a MediaPlayer
    final MediaPlayer yay = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yay);
    final MediaPlayer fail= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fail);
    final MediaPlayer music = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.battle);

    //Button OnClick to enable and loop music
    final Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.song);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            music.setLooping(true);
            music.start();
        }
    });
    //Button OnClick to pause music
    final Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            music.pause();
        }
    });






    //Initiates GridView alongside the ImageAdapter I created
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    //Collections.shuffle(list);
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);





    
    //What happens when you click the card
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        //This section of code enables the position of the code
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (currentPos < 0)
            {
                currentPos = position;
                curView = (ImageView)view;
                ((ImageView)view).setImageResource(drawable[pos[position]]);
                //Whenever an attempt is made give 1 point for tries and remove from attempts left
                tries +=1;
                attempt -=1;


            }

            else
            {
                //If the card is pressed and it is wrong, then say to the user it is incorrect
                if (currentPos == position)
                {
                    ((ImageView)view).setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
                }
                else if (pos[currentPos]!=pos[position])
                {
                    curView.setImageResource(R.drawable.back);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No match, try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //When correct plays the wav fail file below
                    fail.start();
                }
                else
                //If the card is pressed and it is right, then say to the user it is correct
                {
                    ((ImageView)view).setImageResource(drawable[pos[position]]);
                    countPair++;
                    //Add 1 points everytime the user is correct
                    score +=1;
                    //When correct plays the wav yay file below
                    yay.start();


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"That was correct!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    //When all the cards are correct
                    if(countPair==0)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You win!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                //Current position is back

                currentPos = -1;
                //Change text to x + score/tries/attempt
                scoreLabel.setText("Score : " + score);
                tryLabel.setText("Tries : " + tries);
                attemptlabel.setText("Attempts left : " + attempt);

                //If attempts reach 0 then a toast message shows your final score
                if(attempt==0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Game Over!, your final score was : "+ score,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Disables the ability to continue playing until reset
                    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(null);
                    //Changes Match them all to You lose after 0 attempts left
                    finalscore.setText("YOU LOST!");

                }
                //Allows the button to be pressed
                final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.finish);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //Makes a toast message saying games over, alongside how many attempts were successful
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Game Ended! Successful attempts = "+ score,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Makes a toast message showing how many tried were attempted
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Tries Attempted = "+ tries,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Disables onClick on the gridView to stop the game
                        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(null);
                        //Changes the title to Game Ended
                        finalscore.setText("Game Ended");
                        //Accuracy of attempts (How many were correct in a percentage))
                        float endScore = tries / score;
                        float magical = endScore*100;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Total accuracy= "+ magical,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });


}
```

### }

### Then my base adapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter

{ private Context context;
public ImageAdapter(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 16;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null)  //If it is not recycled, initialise some attributes
    {
        //The parameters of the card block.
        imageView = new ImageView(this.context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(350,350));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);

    }
    //Changes the block to "back" which is the cards behind.

    else imageView = (ImageView) convertView;


        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.back);


    //If the card is correct then show the image.
    return imageView;


}
```

Comment: you should keep all logic in adapter, e.g. in its constructor you may make some randomization

Comment: could you help w that im a newb doing stuff idk bout

Comment: Create a function that generate a number between 0 and itemCount - 1. Create an Array of integers i.e. arr. Now generate random number and check if number exists in array if not then add it in array. At the end you have an array of unordered numbers. use these numbers as position for each grid view item.